# Latex TUDelft font change

Tags: fonts

I am not so familiar with Latex and its endless opportunities. However I very much like the layout of the document that I am currently using from my university, but I am unable to change the font. The layout can be downloaded here: https://intranet.tudelft.nl/fileadmin/Files/medewerkersportal/mc/huisstijl/tudelft-report.zip

I would like to play a little with different font options and I know where I can download them. I thought I would just place them in the 'font' folder and change their location in the 'tudelft-report' file. However this is not working for me. So I hope someone can support me in this issue and help me understand what I have to do if I want to change the main font (purely the large text areas/content of the document) of the document.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Hi and welcome, the word `intranet` indicates, that this is limited to your university. Nobody of us can follow the link.

Comment: Hello, thank you. Does it work now? I am not on the university network or logged on to any website.

Comment: Yes, works. i'll take a look at it.

Comment: Are you sure yo are allowed to use different fonts? There is a whole section about fonts in the example/manual. With XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, you can use any Open Type font you like. Try out `\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}`.

Comment: Yes, I am allowed to use different fonts. Also the document has to go to the company which has a different font style and I would like to put it in their style for their use. Are XeLaTeX and LuaLaTex different programs, where I could replace the font style?

Comment: Im not sure where to try the \setmainfont{Liberation Sans} in the documentation. But does not seem to work. The font that I am trying to use is not really a common font such as Liberation Sans, but a company specific. So I have the font .ttf file.

Comment: `\setmainfont{companySpecificFont}\begin{document}`. Install the font on your system. Run with XeLaTeX. A full answer would include explaining general font selection with XeLaTeX and specifics dealt with by the document class. An answer would be huge for what you are asking for. You say you aren't experienced with LaTeX, a good introduction should help you with the basics.